# API Management and Azure Function App - Host Key behavior

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-api-management

We use API management to allow internet traffic in to and out of an Azure Function app's HTTP triggers.

The function app has a Host Key, which is stored in the Named Values of our API Management instance. Each time we pass a request from APIM to the function app, we send the host key in the header.

About a half hour after a recent Function App deployment finished, we observed an uptick in 401 errors reported by API Management. App Insights points to backend 401 errors; in other words, the function app was denying traffic from API Management. Here's what we tried:

- Replacing the host key in API Management with the _master default key

  - This worked, our 401 issue went away without any additional configuration changes
- Making calls from Postman to the function app using the problematic Host Key

  - This also worked, the same key would fail from APIM but succeed from a device on our network
- Regenerating the Host Key

  - This also worked, we were able to drop this key back into APIM and traffic stayed healthy.

I must have a poor understanding of Host Keys.

Do Host Keys expire?

Is there a functional difference between host keys and the _master key?

Can a host key enter some sort of failure state?

Finally, how could regenerating a key resolve this issue with no additional intervention?

We verified the keys still existed on the FA after deployment, so I don't suspect it got blown away. We also don't integrate with KeyVault at this time.

Comment: Host Keys has no expiration, Get clear data b/w the differences of Authorization keys available in azure Functions from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75267370/19615125) provided by @[PravallikaKV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19991670/pravallika-kv)